# Aerospike set TTL for all filtered records with Python

Tags: python, aerospike

I want to set the TTL to -1 (no ttl) for all records that match some filter, using Python.

I successfully set the TTL for all the records with the following:

```
import time

from aerospike_helpers import expressions as exp
from aerospike_helpers.operations import operations

import aerospike

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {
        'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 3000)]
    }

    client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

    ops = [operations.touch(-1)]

    query = client.query('ns123', 'foo')
    query.add_ops(ops)
    expr = exp.GE(exp.LastUpdateTime(), 0).compile()
    policy = {}
    job_id = query.execute_background(policy)
    while True:
        response = client.job_info(job_id, aerospike.JOB_SCAN)
        print(response)
        if response["status"] != aerospike.JOB_STATUS_INPROGRESS:
            break
        time.sleep(0.25)

    client.close()
```

It works, but it produces a deprecationWarning:
`TTL should be specified in the meta dictionary for operate`. the documentation states:

```
ttl (int): Deprecated. The ttl that should be set for the record.
    This should be set in the metadata passed to the operate or
    operate_ordered methods.
```

But how I can do it with `operate` or `operate_oredered` methods? seems like both require keys, and I'm doing this query on all records.

Comment: Quite likely a Python Client issue. The touch(int) still works. But the client should provide an alternate way to set the record ttl via possibly WritePolicy dictionary for execute_background() when they deprecate the touch(int) to touch().

Comment: @pgupta Yeah with Golang it's with a WritePolicy, but in the Python client I didn't find it (for ALL records with a filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This deprecation requires update to Python client which should be forthcoming.

Comment: any ETA? Anyway I ended up using the deprecated TTL - seems to work fine. I shared the script as an answer.

Comment: Its "in progress" ...

Comment: In Python Client ver 7.1.1  - should be out now (9/30/22) or next week.

Answer (score 2):

As @pgupta said, the touch TTL is deprecated, but for now I ended up using it anyway. Seems to work fine.
Sharing the script I'm using. You can add filter expressions in the policy of the query.

```
import time

from aerospike_helpers.operations import operations

import aerospike

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = {
        'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 3000)]
    }

    client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

    zero_ttl_operation = [operations.touch(-1)]
    query = client.query(namespace, set_name)
    query.add_ops(zero_ttl_operation)
    policy = {}
    job = query.execute_background(policy)
    while True:
        response = client.job_info(job, aerospike.JOB_SCAN)
        if response['status'] != aerospike.JOB_STATUS_INPROGRESS:
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)
```